# How can I use digest auth with asp.net web api and angular js without a login form?

Tags: c#, asp.net, wpf, angularjs, digest-authentication

I am building a single page application that is to be solely consumed by users via a WPF application. Never publicly via a traditional browser.

Essentially, the users will have already authenticated via the client WPF application.

The WPF app utilizes an existing web API to consume data and authenticate users.

Once logged into the WPF app, the users can navigate to a section that will load my Single Page App via WPF Browser Control or similar.

The SPA will utilize AngularJS and the same web API as the wpf app.

I would like to authenticate the users to the SPA section on initial page load and secure all API requests made from the SPA. Since the angularjs app needs to access the API, I need a way to get the user credentials into the web portion of the app.

Can I use digest auth on initial page load and somehow store these credentials on the page for use by angularjs? And if so, what is the process for setting this up in asp.net?

Comment: The answer to your question is "Yes, you can".  However, I think you may want to re-word your question, because I'm sure you are actually meaning to ask how to accomplish it, not if it's possible.

Comment: to get you started, you have a token endpoint; you would store the client values you want set in the token, once the token is retrieved, you can then take the values from the token and store them in HTML local storage.

Comment: Thanks @Claies I think first I need to secure the intial HTML page served from IIS, correct? This page would expect digest credentials to authenticate the user(sent from the WPF app) and then I can store a token on the page and use angular + the token to access the API. I need guidance on configuring the auth on initial page

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with Windows dev, but I think I have a similar setup :

1. First you authenticate your user.
2. Then you generate on the server side the main page of your AngularJS app, and include with ng-init an object which contains the results of your previous authentication. My example (syntax for server side generation is ejs) :

   ```
       <body ng-init='{ user = { id : "<%= user._id %>",
           email : "<%= user.local.email %>",
           name :  "<%= user.local.first_name + " " + user.local.last_name %>",
           password : "<%= user.local.password %>",
           apiKey : "<%= user.local.apiKey %>",
       };'>
   ```
3. In the rest of your angularJS app, you'll be able to use $rootScope.user.apiKey or $scope.user.apiKey

I hope this helps.
Good luck with your code.
G

Answer (score 1):

Make the requests from javascript to the server via the WPF app (which can make authenticated calls) using [ObjectForScripting](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.objectforscripting%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). This function allows the hosted JS to call out to the .NET code.